# Using showModal() method with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to show modal dialog, there is function `showModal()` for dialog html element which I using, this method works fine for Chrome browser, using Mozilla I received compatibility issue. How I cant, any way!!!, bypass this error using Mozilla and get show modal dialog. I can use jquery to avoid this Mozilla compatibility issue?
I thank your general recommendations for handling browser's compatibility issues, thanks!!!

A Simple script code:

```
dialog=Document.getElementById(“dialogId");
dialog.showModal(); //Error using Mozilla
```

Comment: Which Frontend framework you are using?

Comment: Correct, this is experimental and not compatible with FF see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dialog.showModal not supported by Mozilla firefox any more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628121/dialog-showmodal-not-supported-by-mozilla-firefox-any-more)

Comment: I using bootstrap!!!

Comment: Jejun I thanks you, your link led me to problem solution using polyfill function showModalDialog.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use bs modal after you are using bootstrap framework isnt be better ?

Here is example of the bs modal

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Click me
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       modal body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can bypass problem with showModal dialog function, in Mozilla FF, using bootstrap modal plugin, but I prefer to use polyfill function showModalDialog, showed at link to another post in comments above, Ivan thank you very much any way for your answer.